# How can I change the youtube subscribe button width?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, youtube

I added a youtube subscribe button on my site but the Firefox version is different from the Chrome's one.

In Chrome the button is wider than in Firefox.
Even, in the full layout the button is bigger than the box.

Is there a way to fix this ?

You can see it here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTW3M.png